# object metadata (cache control) being deleted whenever new version uploaded?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cache-control

Just what it says. I have objects in a bucket that is fully public. I have set the cache control metadata on each one to something (e.g. "public, max-age=60", or "no-store"). Whatever I set it to, it saves fine. However, as soon as I upload a new version of the file, it deletes the metadata. I have tried with object versioning on and off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include the command or code that you are using to upload. When you upload an object with the same name as another object, the object is replaced, not updated. Versioning keeps the previous object as a version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm using their visual interface, not code.
Since the whole point of the cache metadata is to control how new versions of a file are served, I would assume that uploading a new version would not delete the cache metadata. That would be perfectly self defeating.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> The new version replaces the live version and receives a new generation number. The old live version becomes a noncurrent version and keeps the same generation number.

You can edit the value of the `Cache-Control` metadata at any time, but you can only assign the `storageClass` metadata when the object is created or rewritten, and you cannot directly edit the value for the `generation` metadata, though the `generation` value changes when the object is replaced.

Reference:

- [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#reference)
- [Object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#generation-number)

Comment: Thanks--I don't think that answers my question, though. I had no problem editing the Cache-Control metadata. The problem is whenever I upload a new version of the file, it clears whatever was set to Cache-Control. This defeats the purpose of that metadata in the first place, which is to specify how to serve new versions of the file over stale old versions.